# Fingerprint image enhancement (pixel by pixel)

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have a fingerprint project for my final test. I want to create an algorithm to compare fingerprint image. I have do some little research and create an android application to prove my concept. At first, I want to do image enhancement in the fingerprint scan result so it will be easier to do the next step.

What I am doing are like this :

1. Convert the image to black and white mode
2. Scan the pixel color and store the result to two dimension array, the index will be the X and Y coordinate, and the value will be like this, if the color is white, the value is 0, and if black, the value is 1.
3. If the array value is 1, then Compare the value of array with the 8 points around the coordinate of the array.If the array is not have any "1" value around it. then the array value will change to 0.
4. Scan the array and if the value is 0, that it's mean a white pixel, then compare the coordinate with the coordinate in X+1 and X-1, if the value of index X+1 and the value of index X-1 is 1, that it's mean a black pixel, then change the array value to 1. and another condition is if Y+1 = 1 and Y-1=1, then convert the array value to 1.
5. Then scan the bitmap and compare the coordinate with the array, if the array value is 1, then set pixel of the bitmap to black, and if 0, then change the pixel of bitmap to white.

So far the bitmap result of this method is better than before. But the bitmap still have the white pixel that surrounded by the black pixel, so it's look like a hole in the bitmap.What I want to ask is if you have any method or steps how to change this hole coordinate pixel to black so the thinning method will be easier to do. The picture of original image and the result of the method above is include in below. Please take a look.

[image: progress]

Please give your advise or anything to me to help me solve the problem. If you have another method that will works better, feel free to post it here.

Thanks before...

Regards

Comment: There are several reference points, most algorithms use them to compare fingerprints. A search on Google will be inspiring

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you have any experience with this topic?can you more details, what points or algorithm that need to be search on google?

Comment: No... but here's a quick Google search [fingerprint points of identification](https://www.google.it/#q=fingerprint+points+of+identification)